# jQuery metadata, how to get the value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, metadata

I'm having a tough time getting the value of a key in the data attribute. I'm using the jquery metadata plugin.

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery.metadata.setType("attr", "data");

$('ul li').each(function () {  
   console.log($(this).metadata())
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li data="{someKey:'someValue',anotherKey:'anotherValue'}">Some List Item</li>
   <li data="{someKey:'someValue2',anotherKey:'anotherValue2'}">Some List Item 2</li>
   <li data="{someKey:'someValue3',anotherKey:'anotherValue3'}">Some List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I am outputting the object, but have no idea how to get at the value. I've tried `$(this).metadata().someKey` and `$(this).metadata('someKey')` and now I am grasping for straws.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want this:

```
myMeta = $(this).metadata();
```

Then you can access `myMeta.someKey` or `myMeta.anotherKey` - whatever meta keys you have set.